# Get a List of all listening servers on a port on the LAN in C#

Tags: c#, networking, client, lan

Suppose I want to check see which hosts are listening for a connection on a specific port on the local area network, How would this be accomplished in C#. The reason i want this is so that I can connect to a server thats listening on the LAN by specifying the host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a portscan, but one where it scans a subnet for 1 single port? Ok, what you need is `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` and 64 or so `System.Threading.Thread`s.

Answer (score -1):

possible only with connection orianted protocols like TCP.

why not just iterate the computers in the network trying taking a socket and trying to connect to the port you are probing?